# Why can't my MATLAB program execute an if statement block?

Tags: matlab, statistics

In the code below, my MDD matrix is 38*270 and my Normal Matrix is 28*270，I try to display all the p values, and find there are many p less than 0.05 but the program doesn't execute the if statement block. Why?

```
for i=1:270
  [h,p] = kstest2(MDD(:,i),Normal(:,i));
  num=0;
  fprintf('%d\n',p);
  if p<0.05
      num=num+1;
      Select_MDD=MDD(:,i);
      filename=['F:\',num2str(i),'.mat'];
      save filename Select_MDD;  
  end
end
```

Comment: you can't just tell people "it won't execute" without providing error messages. otherwise, no one can help you. Also, your `fprintf('%d')` is incorrect, should be `%f` or `%e`

Comment: Have a look on [How to ask and how to create a MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)